# Searching for Uppercase words in multiple cells and returning in a specific cell

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which contains addresses. The City is shown in uppercase, however, the city could be present on any of the 5 columns. I am wanting to create a formula which will search the 5 columns in the row and return the City, where the whole word in in uppercase.

I have searched this site and others and I can only fnd code which will split out words that start with uppercase.

Comment: So, what have you tried with the code you have found, showing attempts is good.

Comment: will any other values in the 5 columns range in UPPER case as well? i.e. only the city name will be in UPPER case while other info in the other four columns are not fully UPPER case. Please clarify.

Comment: Hi @TerryW, the other columns are all in proper case. Column 1 will be street name, then depending on the amount of lines that the address has, column 2 will be either City or Area and Column 3 will be blank or City. I am new to this site, so unsure how to put a picture of what I have. It wont paste in :-( Thanks Ben

Answer (score 0):

Given that the city name will be the only word in uppercase in the 5-column range, you can use either of the following formulas to find the city name:

```
=INDEX(AV2:AZ2,SUMPRODUCT(EXACT(UPPER(AV2:AZ2),AV2:AZ2)*NOT(ISBLANK(AV2:AZ2))*COLUMN(AV2:AZ2)))
```

or

```
=INDEX(AV2:AZ2,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(AV2:AZ2)/(EXACT(UPPER(AV2:AZ2),AV2:AZ2)*NOT(ISBLANK(AV2:AZ2))),1))
```

Replace `AV2:AZ2` with the first row of your actual data, and drag the formula down to apply across board.

The logic is to:

1. use **UPPER** function to convert all text strings in the 5-column range to uppercase, and compare the converted string with the original one using **EXACT**, the only match would be city name;
2. use either **AGGREGATE** or **SUMPRODUCT** to find out the column number (between 1 to 5) where the city name locates, with the help of using **NOT+ISBLANK** to eliminate the impact of blank cells;
3. use the location number in an **INDEX** formula to return the actual city name.

See below screen-shot for more clarifications.
[image: Solutions]

Although both of them are **array formulas**, there is no need to press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` when using **SUMPRODUCT** or **AGGREGATE** in this case.

Cheers :)

Comment: Hi Terry, that is great. It works perfectly when the address starts on Column A, however, when I move the formula (and update the A2:E2 to the applicable columns AV2:AZ2 for example) it comes up with a #REF.Any ideas if this is correctable. Thank you for your time so far

Comment: @BenDenby in each of my solution `A2:E2` was referred **5** times. If you missed to replace any one of them with `AV2:AZ2` will result in the `#REF` error. I have updated the formulas in my solution to use `AV2:AZ2` instead. Try again and let me know if it is now working for you.